# Building Servers For Web Applications

Tags: node.js, server, localhost, hosting

**Question(s)**

- I would like to deploy a server for a relatively basic HTML, CSS, JS website. I want it to be able to run all of the time, and for *potentially 1000s of people to view it each day. Technically I will not need to store any data, above what is included in the code.

a. Can I use Node.JS to do this, through setting up a local server? e.g. by connecting a domain to it etc.

b. Could I use Node.JS to do this through alternative means - rather than using a local server.

c. Would a service like Firebase solve the problem, and nullify the need for any server building on Node.JS

d. If I did need to store a lot of data e.g. sale orders, email addresses, account info: stuff like that, would it change any of the answers.

I have been putting a lot of research into what the best way to host my website would be, but these were the questions that remained unresolved. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Firebase Hosting is one key for a static website.
- Firebase Functions can be used if you are looking for any computation/manipulations.
- Firebase Database can be used for storage and retrieval of data as documents.

**As per your question:**

a. Yes, you can serve your files using [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve). Later you need a static IP and then point it to your domain.

b. You can use Firebase Hosting, GitHub Pages. But you can't use Node.JS in this case.

c. Yes, definitely it would cover up all the stuff with a Spark Plan for initial deployment.

d. In this case, go for a Firebase Database or Mongodb Atlas.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: this is really useful! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Heroku server (https://www.heroku.com/)
You can run a server on it completely for free for the first 100ds of users. If you want to include a DB, you can run MongoDB Atlas for DB storing, though if you don't really need DB, you can just use Heroku for a free server.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/ this is the documentation